# inserting and updating at the same time

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I change the existing data in my db while inserting new field

this is my code

```
$sql = array(
                'company_id' => $this->company_id,
                'template_name' => $temp_name,
                'temp_default' => $temp_default,
                'region_name' => $region_name,
                'division_name' => $division_name,
                'division_address' => $division_address,
                'document_title' => $document_title,
                'division_logo' => $division_logo,
                'deped_logo' => $deped_logo,
                'created_date' =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'created_by_account_id' => $this->account_id
        );

        $sql1 = array(
                'temp_default' => 'No'
        );

        if($temp_default == 'Yes'){
            $f = $this->dsm->default_temp($this->company_id,"Yes");
            print_r($f->template_id);
            $this->db->where('template_id',$f->template_id);
            $this->db->set('temp_default', 'No', FALSE);
            $this->db->update('template',$sql1);
            $this->db->insert('template',$sql);
            echo json_encode(array(
                    "success" => true
            ));
        }
        else{
            $this->db->insert('template',$sql);
            echo json_encode(array(
                    "success" => true
            ));
        }
```

I can insert new field but the other field are not updating/changed.

Comment: in update u must need the WHERE clause

Comment: @devpro their I edit it slightly i have already WHERE

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization: What is `$sql` here?

Comment: Remove the `$his->db->set`, when you use the `$this->db->update` you are passing the array of data so no need to set it as well.

Comment: @BhavikShah the one that gonna insert new field

Comment: @Blinkydamo oh i see i owe you one

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization: i meant to say that, I don't see `$sql` definition.

Comment: @BhavikShah ahh its from input i didnt put it coz only the update all i need